# Cannot compile MySQL++

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql++

I am trying to compile [MySQL++ 3.1.0](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/) with the command:

```
mingw32-make -f Makefile.mingw
```

After a set of files gets compiled (e.g. beemutex.cpp, cmdline.cpp, connection.cpp, ...), I get these errors:

```
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_sql_buffer.o -g -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include"   -MT
mysqlpp_sql_buffer.o -MFmysqlpp_sql_buffer.o.d -MD -MP lib/sql_buffer.cpp
In file included from lib/sql_buffer.h:31:0,
                 from lib/sql_buffer.cpp:26:
lib/refcounted.h:258:2: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
lib/refcounted.h: In constructor 'mysqlpp::RefCountedPointer<T, Destroyer>::RefCountedPointer()':
lib/refcounted.h:89:2: error: class 'mysqlpp::RefCountedPointer<T, Destroyer>' does not have any field named 'refs_'
lib/refcounted.h: In constructor 'mysqlpp::RefCountedPointer<T, Destroyer>::RefCountedPointer(T*)':
lib/refcounted.h:100:2: error: class 'mysqlpp::RefCountedPointer<T, Destroyer>' does not have any field named 'refs_'
lib/refcounted.h:104:4: error: 'refs_' was not declared in this scope
lib/refcounted.h:104:16: error: expected type-specifier before 'size_t'
lib/refcounted.h:104:16: error: expected ';' before 'size_t'
lib/refcounted.h: In constructor 'mysqlpp::RefCountedPointer<T, Destroyer>::RefCountedPointer(const ThisType&)':
lib/refcounted.h:112:2: error: class 'mysqlpp::RefCountedPointer<T, Destroyer>' does not have any field named 'refs_'
lib/refcounted.h:115:8: error: 'refs_' was not declared in this scope
lib/refcounted.h: In destructor 'mysqlpp::RefCountedPointer<T, Destroyer>::~RefCountedPointer()':
lib/refcounted.h:125:7: error: 'refs_' was not declared in this scope
lib/refcounted.h: In member function 'void mysqlpp::RefCountedPointer<T, Destroyer>::swap(mysqlpp::RefCountedPointer<T, Destroyer>::ThisType&)':
lib/refcounted.h:246:13: error: 'refs_' was not declared in this scope
mingw32-make: *** [mysqlpp_sql_buffer.o] Error 1
```

Something could be wrong in my configuration, but I can't find what. It seems strange that it cannot find, e.g., `size_t`.

Thank you!

*Platform:*
Windows 7
MinGW 2011.09 / GCC 4.6.1
MySQL 5.5
[mysql++ 3.1.0](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/)

Answer (score 1):

Changing `size_t()` with `std::size_t()` in `refcounted.h` solved the problem. It now compiles.

I still have linking problems, but they should be different issues.

Comment: The official fix is `#include <stddef.h>`. This was necessitated by GCC changes since MySQL++ 3.1.0 was released. You can get all such changes by getting MySQL++ from the repository instead of the tarball. It is in a good, stable state right now, just not yet in a state where I want to make another release.